# How to prevent a specified task from firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, checkbox, element

everyone!

How can I prevent a certain event(s) from firing, when I click on an element?
I have a table with a checkbox on each row's first cell. When I click on a cell, an event is called which paints a row of the clicked cell in some color.
It works great, however, it also gets fired when I click on a checkbox. I don't want that to happen.
I don't want these checkboxes to affect the table in any way.
I want to do it via javascript and, preferably, jQuery.
Any recommendations?

Comment: you should share some relevant code like table and checkbox structur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `e.stopPropagation()` to stop event bubling to parent element.

```
$('#tableId tr td input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: I did tried that earlier, it didn't work though. Now it works. Magic of programming :D

Comment: might be something wrong earlier. happy to help you :)